# Объясните каким образом происходит преобразование в данном примере JS

Tags: javascript, преобразование-типов

```
setTimeout('console.log('+ i +')', 1000);
```

Comment: по идее пишется так `setTimeout(function(){ console.log(i); }, 1000);`

Comment: Да, согласен, но я так понимаю здесь еще прописано преобразование к строчному типу данных.

Comment: Так вас интересует setTimeout или преобразование `i` к строке?

Answer (score 1):

Вроде как интерпретатор создаёт анонимную функцию из этой строки. Это выражение эквивалентно `setTimeout(eval('console.log('+ i +')'), 1000)`

Comment: Только`eval` произойдёт не сейчас, а через секунду. Это важное отличие.